# how does grid system compensate for variation in column heights?

Tags: css, grid-system

Below I am using an extraction from a 12-grid 960px system.

```
<style>
body {
  background: gray;
}

#container_12 {
   width: 960px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   background: white;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.column_1, .column_2, .column_3, .column_4, .column_5, .column_6, .column_7, .column_8, .column_9, .column_10, .column_11, .column_12 {
  float : left;
  margin-left : 10px;
  margin-right : 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
} 

.column_1 {
  width : 60px;
}

.column_2 {
  width : 140px;
}

.column_3 {
  width : 220px;
}

.column_4 {
  width : 300px;
}

.column_5 {
  width : 380px;
}

.column_6 {
  width : 460px;
}

.column_7 {
  width : 540px;
}

.column_8 {
  width : 620px;
}

.column_9 {
  width : 700px;
}

.column_10 {
  width : 780px;
}

.column_11 {
  width : 860px;
}

.column_12 {
  width : 940px;
} 

</style>

<body>
  <div id="container_12">

    <!-- First row -->
      <div class="column_1" style="height: 400px; background: red;">
      </div>
      <div class="column_11" style="height: 200px; background: red;">
      </div>

    <!-- Second row -->
    <!--
    This column overlaps into second row
    <div class="column_1">
    </div>
     -->

      <div class="column_5" style="height: 200px; background: green;">
      </div>
      <div class="column_3" style="height: 200px; background: green;">
      </div>
      <div class="column_3" style="height: 200px; background: green;">
      </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

The output:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/hnDtY/
```

Now let's say if I copy the two rows above to have a total of 4 rows. But I want to give the first two rows a purple background and the last two rows a white background:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/QZuED/
```

The problem with what I did above is I had to create a new div called "row" and wrap it around the two columns. This makes it inconsistent from the rest of the layout which does not have a div "row" wrapping every row. If I added a div "row" on each row and gave it a overflow: hidden property, then it will be impossible to have one column span two rows, because it would push the items in the second row down. So how do grid systems handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, nesting the blocks inside of a div would force them to be unable to extend into the rest of the content.  The answer I find most commonly used is a repeating background image instead.

```
body {
    background: gray url(web.png) repeat-x;
}
```

This would also allow you to use a gradient that fades into the rest of the background.  Here's your jsfiddle [tweaked to reflect this](http://jsfiddle.net/QZuED/2/).

Comment: Then how does this system get away with having row divs surround each set of columns: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/

Comment: Because it does not attempt to extend any divs from one "row" div into another.  It appears to function much like the second example you listed.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: so adding a repeating background image or nesting multiple columns in a row div with a property of overflow:hidden are seriously the only solutions possible (without resorting to tables)?